# How can I find the mean score when using the following Likert scale

Tags: average

I have some quantitative data in the form of Likert scale, and I would like to obtain the mean score for each question. I am using +2.0 = ‘Strongly Agree’, +1.0 = ‘Agree’, 0.0 = ‘Not Sure’, -1.0 = ‘Disagree’, -2.0 = ‘Strongly Disagree’.

If I had 8 participants and these were the responses:

[Set of responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBhZH.png)

I am getting a mean score of -0.625. However I thought that a mean score in the proximity of +2.0 indicates that the respondents strongly agree whilst a -2.0 indicates that they strongly disagree. I am getting -0.625 by diving the total score by 8. Not sure if that is what is to be done. Or if I am misinterpreting what the mean score is saying.

Addendum:

**Likert scale** is used to collect respondents' opinions. This psychometric scale is used to understand the views and perspectives towards your research.

Comment: Since you have 5 to 8 responses "disagree" or "strongly disagree", the sample average is mostly dominated by negative values.

Comment: Ok, so the way I am analysing the data is correct. Sorry I guess I just needed to go over the working with someone else to be sure.

Comment: Also, to improve readability, consider writing the data directly on the post.

Comment: "Likert scale" is **unknown** to most people; you should give a (good) reference for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is the vector $(-1, 2, 0,-1,0,-2,-2,-1)$, and the sample average is
$$
\bar x = (-1 + 2 + 0 -1 + 0 - 2 - 2 - 1)/8 = -0.625.
$$

This means that the overall opinion of the people in the sample in this sample (about whatever you are studying) is about 'disagree'.